# Relation between Gaussian and bi-Gaussian distribution

Tags: signal-analysis, digital-communications, frequency-spectrum, power-spectral-density, dsp-core

A Gaussian Doppler Spectrum can be seen as a bi-Gaussian Doppler spectrum in wich only one Gaussian function is present ( the second having a zero power gain) ?

any help will be really appreciated

Comment: Can you please add a bit more context to this question? Any Gaussian can be seen as a bi-Gaussian with only one gaussian present (!). What is the context?

Comment: The context is the simulation of some HF  channels where the implementation of Rayleigh fading and Bi-Gaussian Doppler spectrum (with a zero gain for the second gaussian component ) is used by matlab intead of having a Rayleigh fading and Gaussien Doppler spectrum.

Comment: you can find the matlab code by taping in your Matlab cmd window openExample('comm/HFIonosphericChannelModelExample') : provided that you have the signal processing tool